# Как увеличить размер recyclerView item'a?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Всем привет, у меня есть recyclerView, нужно сделать так чтобы итемы(фотки) стали больше, как можно программно сделать? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Разметка ресайклера:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView 
     android:id="@+id/bottom_recycler_view" 
     android:layout_width="match_parent" 
     android:layout_height="@dimen/bottom_recycler_height" 
     android:background="@color/colorLayoutBackground" 
     android:gravity="center_vertical" 
     android:orientation="horizontal" />
```

Comment: Добавьте разметку вашего recycler'а

Comment: <code><android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/bottom_recycler_height"
        android:background="@color/colorLayoutBackground"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />
</LinearLayout><code>

Comment: Нужна разметка строки (айтема) ресайклера... - редактируйте сообщение, а не комментариями